# Read/Write to xml that was generated using csd

Tags: c#, .net, xml, save, config

I've used the Configuration Section Designer (csd) to generate an xml configuration file to my application.

Now, I want to work with this xml file (on c#) and do 2 things:

**1.** read a specific value (searching by its field), something like

```
txtbox_username.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"];
```

**2.** write a specific value, something like

```
config.AppSettings.Settings["userName"].Value = txtbox_username.Text;

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");
```

- p.s: this is how i perform read/write for regular xml files that looks like this:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
add key="userName" value="Value1"
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

---

but the csd generated xml looks different...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="sectionName" type="Sample.ConfigurationSection.sectionName, Sample.ConfigurationSection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </configSections>
  <sectionName xmlns="Sample.ConfigurationSection">
    <logFile debugLevel="3"  filePath="c:\new" maxFileCount="10" maxFileLength="1000"/>
    <results path="C:\Results"/>
    <details user="blabla" pass="12345" code="abc"/>
    <stuff fromAddress="from@gmail.com" toAddress="to@gmail.com" sendMail="true""/>
  </sectionName>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

here, I want to edit and save, for example, user/pass/code fields.

Answer (score 0):

In short (and using these extensions: http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki) you can do this to read/write the user,

```
XElement file = XElement.Load(xmlFile);
XNamespace ns = "Sample.ConfigurationSection";
XElement section = file.GetElement(ns + "sectionName");
string user = section.Get("details/user", string.Empty);
section.Set("details/user", "bubba", true); // true = set as attribute
file.Save(xmlFile);
```